# i have error with the sample rate 8khz to read real time audio buffer

Tags: swift3, avfoundation, xcode8

with my following code i have the error :

```
var engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let input = engine.inputNode!
    let bus = 0

    let mixer = AVAudioMixerNode()
    engine.attach(mixer)

    engine.connect(input, to: mixer, format: input.outputFormat(forBus: 0))
    //pcmFormatFloat64 -- pcmFormatFloat32
    let fmt = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 8000, channels: 1, interleaved: true)

    mixer.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 512, format: fmt) { (buffer, time) -> Void in
        // 8kHz buffers!
        print(buffer.format)
    }

    try! engine.start()
}
```

ERROR :   `kAudioUnitErr_TooManyFramesToProcess : inFramesToProcess=1024, mMaxFramesPerSlice=768`

with the sample rate 441khz is everything fine but with 8khz not

what is wrong with this code ?

Comment: do you really mean that it works at a 441kHz sample rate? Or did you mean 44.1kHz? 441kHz is a *really* fast sample rate. Does it work if you remove the `print`? That can be very slow (since it locks the console), and could certainly cause real-time processing to pile up.

Comment: <AVAudioFormat 0x17408f820:  1 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32>
this is the output from my buffer.format

Comment: Right; that's 44.1kHz. And does it work w/o the print?

Comment: yes the print is working fine  and i know that is really fast. I just want to save my buffer into an array with 8000 sample rate. and the print is just to ensure the sample rate

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message at 8kHz and fixed it by setting the preferred sampling rate and capture duration for my audio session instance:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(sampleRate)
try audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(TimeInterval(processingInterval))
```